# How to convert time to standard format and calculate time difference

Tags: r, date, time

```
newdf=data.frame(date=as.Date(c("2021-01-04","2021-01-05","2021-01-06","2021-01-07")),
                 time=c("10:32:29","11:25","12:18:42","09:58"))
```

This is my data frame. I want to calculate time difference between two consecutive days in hours. Could you please suggest a method to calculate? Note, some time values do not contain seconds. So, first we have to convert it to standard form. Could you please give me a method to solve all these problems. This is completely R programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste `date` and `time` together in one column, use `parse_date_time` to change the time value in standard format (Posixct) and use `difftime` to calculate difference between consecutive time in hours.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

newdf %>%
  unite(datetime, date, time, sep = ' ') %>%
  mutate(datetime = parse_date_time(datetime, c('Ymd HMS', 'Ymd HM')), 
         difference_in_hours = round(as.numeric(difftime(datetime,
                                     lag(datetime), 'hours')), 2))

#             datetime difference_in_hours
#1 2021-01-04 10:32:29                  NA
#2 2021-01-05 11:25:00               24.88
#3 2021-01-06 12:18:42               24.90
#4 2021-01-07 09:58:00               21.66
```